# Is assigning DataTable to ViewState a good way to persist data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, viewstate, state-management

I'm getting a DataTable from a database and assigning to ViewState like below because I don't want to hit my database every time and just want to check a DataTable for subsequent look ups.

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTable();
ViewState["dtTable"] = dt;
```

`GetDataTable()` is a method which retrieves 1000 records from the database.

Is this the best way or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ViewState Vs Session ... maintaining object through page lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883149/viewstate-vs-session-maintaining-object-through-page-lifecycle)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several options. Which one is best to use depends a lot on your requirements, environments settings, etc.

#### Viewstate:

The viewstate is stored in a hidden field rendered as an `<input />` tag in the final HTML sent to the browser. When the user initiates a postback (via button click, etc.), the data is sent back to the server as part of the submitted form data.

If you store large amounts of data in the ViewState, you will have to incur a penalty when the user attempts to download the page because all that data will be part of your HTML and also when the user attempts to submit the form because again this data will be sent back to server.

In addition, the ViewState is easily lost. It is only preserved as long as the user is submitting the form. If the user clicks a hyperlink to another page, the form is not submitted and therefore data contained within the ViewState is lost.

It is recommended to use the ViewState if the data is relatively small.

If we consider security options, ViewState data is encoded in base64, which can be easily decoded. This is a classic example for hacking a website, so crosscheck what data exactly you are storing. You can overcome this issue by setting `EnableViewStateMac` to true.

---

#### Session

***For large amounts of data***, Session is a good option. If you are able to detect when any user is done with a particular block of data, set the Session variable to null, to counter memory overhead issues. If you can't always do this, the Session will also expire, and the memory will be reclaimed automatically. Lowering the Session timeout can also help, but take care in setting it to a value that interferes with normal site usage.

Also, the data in the Session is actually present on the web server between page loads. This helps in keeping the page size small; it only has to utilize the Session ID.

---

#### Caching

One last option is to use caching. Check the Microsoft Learn article [*ASP.NET Caching: Techniques and Best Practices*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa478965(v=msdn.10)) by Steven A. Smith for more information.

Comment: So Session and Cache is best way for this?

Comment: I believe more in caching, since the DataTable contains data usually  used for Site wide Data like in GridView. Session is used mainly for User specific data. If you have to store DataTable on user basis then definitely Session is a good way indeed.

Answer (score 2):

View State Side effects

1)It is serialized into the input value and deserialized on its way back.

2)The viewstate is stored in a hidden  tag on the form. When the user initiates a postback (by clicking a button, for example), the data is returned to the server as part of the form data. It could slow things down.

3)ViewState is easily lost. It is only preserved as long as the user is submitting the form. If the user clicks a hyperlink to another page, the form is never submitted and all the data contained within the ViewState is lost. This is true even if the anchor tag points back to the page the user is currently on.

I would use the **ASP.NET Cache** to store these datatables for the following reasons.

1)Cache has an expiry, which means you can automatically remove it based upon a sliding or absolute expiry timed value

2)Cache will automatically be removed if the processes memory "pressure" is too high.

3)You can make a cached item specific to one user, or global to all users based upon its key

Comment: What about using Session? Session is better than viewstate or not?

Comment: Session variables will use different session variables for each different user. Usually a large amount of data can be stored on the session, however web sites that have a large amount of traffic usually would not use this method, as it would put a severe load on the server memory.

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is not a bad way but when on large data it's better to save your data in a Session variable that has an expiry date you can control

Answer (score 0):

Using a DataTable would work. However a DataTable is basically a dynamic object and code in the view tends to be difficult to debug.

I would suggest creating a class or struct that holds the properties you need.Then convert the DataTable to a list instances of this class, and send that to the view instead.

This will make the code more readable, because now any programmer can see what data you are trying to retrieve. And it will prevent you from having to debug the view a lot.

Answer (score 0):

View State is good way store Data Table in view state

Store data table into viewstate

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
ViewState["dttable"]=dt;
```

And now ViewState data into Datatable

```
DataTable dtnin=(DataTable)ViewState["dttable"];
```