# How to save data on cs.file on hold

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that returns data from my DB, I need to save this data in my cs.file on hold.
Any idea how to do that ?
 this is my function : 
 I need to save  m_newId for later use

```
string m_newId;

public void UserInfo(string id, string fullName)
{
   if (id == "0")
    {
        NewId = _WS.AddUser(fullName); //_WS - id my server
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(NewId);
        m_newId = doc.SelectSingleNode("IDENTITY").InnerText;

    }
    else
    {               
        _WS.UpdateUser(id, fullName);

    }    
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you ultimately want to pull off, but you should probably be saving it anywhere else other than the c# file.  Amoung other things, should you actually successfully write to the c# file and it's not proper code and that cs file ever gets compiled again, it will likely break or give you unintended consequences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Pick one**

**ViewState**

> Viewstate is a hidden fields in an ASP.NET page, contains state of
>   those controls on a page whose "EnableViewstate" property is "true".
>
> You can also explicitly add values in it, on an ASP.NET page like:
>
> Viewstate.Add( "TotalStudents", "87" );
>
> Viewstate should be used when you want to save a value between
>   diferent roundtrips of a single page as viewstate of a page is not
>   accessible by another page.
>
> Because Viewstate renders with the page, it consumes bandwith, so be
>   careful to use it in applications to be run on low bandwith.

**Session**

> Session variables are usually the most commonly used.
>
> When a user visits a site, it's sessions starts and when the user
>   become idle or leave the site, the session ends.
>
> Session variables should be used to save and retrive user specefic
>   information required on multiple pages.
>
> Session variables consumes server memory, so if your may have a huge
>   amount visiters, use session very carefully and instead of put large
>   values in it try to put IDs and references

**Cookies**

> Cookies are some values saved in browsers by the website to retrivbbe
>   and use afterwards.
>
> Usually cookies are used to help dynamic websites to identify visitors
>   and retrieve their saved preferences.
>
> Cookies are also used to facilitate auto login by persisting user id
>   in a cookie save in user's browser.
>
> Because cookies have been saved at client side, they do not create
>   performance issues but may create security issues as they can be
>   hacked from browser.

**Cache**

> Cache is probably the least used state feature of ASP.NET.
>
> Cache is basically a resource specific state persistence feature,
>   means unlike session it stick with resource instead of user, for
>   instance: pages, controls etc.
>
> Cache should be used or frequently used pages, controls, and data
>   structures
>
> Data cache can be used to cache frequently used list of values e.g.
>   list of products

**Application**

> Application variables are shared variables among all users of a web
>   application
>
> Application variables behave like static variables and they are
>   substitute of static variables as static variables are stateless in
>   web applications
>
> Only shared values should be persisted in Application variables, and
>   as soon as they are not in use they should be removed explicitly.

---

**Also**

- [ViewState Vs Session … maintaining object through page lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883149/viewstate-vs-session-maintaining-object-through-page-lifecycle)
- [How to Choose From Viewstate, Session, Application, Cache, and Cookies](http://www.articlesbase.com/programming-articles/how-to-choose-from-viewstate-session-application-cache-and-cookies-443393.html)
- [Difference between Asp.net SessionState and ViewState in C#, VB.NET](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/aspnet-difference-between-viewstate-and.html)

---

> ***Finally remember the following points on your finger-tips:***
>
> - Viewstate is bandwidth hungry
> - Session variables are memory hungry as per number of users
> - Applications variables are shared
> - Cache is memory hungry as per number of resources
> - Cookies are the least secure